# Navigator navigatorKey parameters error (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some error

```
  TabNavigator({this.navigatorKey, this.tabItem});

  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;
  final TabItem tabItem;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
```

**The parameter 'navigatorKey' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.**

How to fix this error?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the navigator key that you have defined is of type Global key but right now its null unless its passed from another class. So you have to mark it as required

```dart
TabNavigator({required this.navigatorKey, required this.tabItem}),
```